# Integrated to do list displaying issues from multiple sources

Tags: windows, osx, issue-tracker, task-management

I am looking for a to-do application/dashboard that can display my tasks from multiple sources. Right now I have tasks in:

- Wunderlist
- Exchange (including flagged e-mails - would like those picked up)
- GitHub
- BitBucket
- Sometimes Trello

I would like to be able to open one app (local for Windows and possibly Mac preferred, web acceptable with very strong privacy policy) and see Things I Need To Do in one place.

I am aware of [tacoapp](http://tacoapp.com), but haven't found its user interface to be a very good fit for my working style.

Bi-directional sync to put tasks from other sources into Wunderlist and allow me to at least close, and ideally edit titles & descriptions, them from Wunderlist is a suitable solution (I do not need to be able to add new GitHub tasks from the integrated view).

I would consider replacing Wunderlist with something else to achieve integration.

I may just write some Python scripts to sync Wunderlist and issues, but would prefer pre-existing software if suitable software exists.